# Modify the size of the tickPositions in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, highcharts

I would like to know how to modify the spacing between `tickPositions: [0, 80, 90, 100]`, since if it is represented in this way, there is a very large space between 0 and 80. I want to out 0 but that that space is minimal.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            borderColor: '#025577',
            borderWidth: 4,
            borderRadius: 10,
            zoomType: 'xy',
            spacingBottom: 30
        },
        title: { 
        text: 'PORCENTAJE DE APROBACIÓN EN I Y II CICLOS,<br>SEGÚN AÑO            ',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: '',
            x: -20
        },
            credits: {
        text:'FUENTE: Departamento de Análisis Estadístico,MEP',
        href: '#'
        ,
        style: {
           cursor: 'pointer',
           color: '#000000',
           fontSize: '12px',
           fontWeight: 'bold',
           padding: '50px'

                                 },
        position: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 40,

        }

           },
        xAxis: {categories: [ '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007',  
                        '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'],tickInterval: 2, 
        },
        yAxis: {
        min: 80,

         tickPositions: [80, 80, 90, 100],/*en esta parte si cambio el 
             primer 80 por 0 el grafico como estadistimente debe ser donde el grafico 
          inicia en cero ....  pero visualmente no representa los datos y si tiene el 
         80 al inicio los datos se ven bien pero el cero importante a nivel estadistico 
          no esta*/

            title: {
                text: 'TASA'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '%'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: '1º',
            data: [85.5,    85.6,   84.9,   85.3,   84.3,   83.7,   83.3,   88.5, 
        86.5,   86.3,   86.7,   86.9 ]
        }, {
            name: '2º',
            data: [91.3,    91.2,   90.9,   90.9,   89.6,   89.7,   90.2,   93.3, 
   90.9,    91.6,   92.4,   92.8 ]
        }, {
            name: '3º',
            data: [92.1,    92.6,   91.8,   91.4,   90.3,   90.0,   90.6,   94.2,   
       93.0,    92.8,   93.5,   93.9 ]
        }, {
            name: '4º',
            data: [89.5,    89.8,   88.9,   88.5,   86.5,   85.8,   87.1,   90.8,   
         89.8,  89.6,   90.2,   90.1 ]
        },{
            name: '5º',
            data: [91.5,    92.0,   91.8,   91.7,   90.2,   90.5,   91.5,   94.9,   
             93.9,  93.5,   94.0,   93.5 
                ]
        }, {
            name: '6º',
            data: [96.9,    97.3,   97.2,   96.5,   92.7,   93.9,   94.6,   96.8,   
                 95.9,  95.3,   95.4,   96.0
                       ]
                        }
        ]
                          });
                             });


    '
```

Comment: puede escribir en Inglés?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is in Spanish

Comment: Your question is similar to this one: [Highcharts library : How to produce different scales between bands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988625/highcharts-library-how-to-produce-different-scales-between-bands). It seems it is not possible to do that.

Comment: Instead of `min: 80, tickPositions[...],` you can use just `tickInterval: 10`. But it is not solution for you if you want to explicitly show 0.

Comment: why do you want to do this?  It is - generally speaking - a very bad idea.  Knowing your reasons for doing it may help find alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is what is called a scale break. Currently HC does no support that.